# ArcPy dissolve field changes output field name pattern

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, dissolve, error-000728

I am using the Dissolve tool to summarize two point feature classes (`item` in list). The general pattern of the fields within each `item` are:

```
rankx_dest rankx_length rankx_cost
```

e.g., rank1_dest field.

These are the `statistics_fields_dissolve` fields being passed in the code below.

```
statistics_fields_list= ["_dest",
                                "_cost",
                                "_length",
                                "_paved",
                                "_dirt",
                                "_rail",
                                "_boat",
                                "_trans"]
        statistics_fields_dissolve= []

for i in range(1,21):
    for stat in statistics_fields_list:
        stats_field= "rank" + str(i) + stat + " MAX;"
        statistics_fields_dissolve.append(stats_field)

arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features= item, out_feature_class= item + "_dissolved", dissolve_field="OriginID", statistics_fields= statistics_fields_dissolve, multi_part="MULTI_PART", unsplit_lines="DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

Then I am passing the input fields in a feature class (from a .gdb) to change them.

```
item= item + "_dissolved"
        print "changing name for", item
        for i in statistics_fields_in:
            print i
            for e in statistics_fields_out:
                print e
                arcpy.AlterField_management(item, i, e)
```

However, I get an error `ERROR 000728: Field MAX_rank1_dest does not exist within table`

When I check the feature classes, the error makes sense in Python.
[image: screenshot of dissolve output]

However, I have no idea why the loop is outputting the first field with `MAX` first. It does not do this for the second feature class item, nor does it do this for any other field.

I would like to make this field consistent with the other output fields during the dissolve operation, such that the field is `MAX_rank1_dest`.

Here is what the original attribute table of the two `items` are before I run dissolve
[image: item 1- with the problem output field]
[image: item 2- no problem with output name pattern]

Comment: I added the screenshots. I have to use the dissolved points to do a spatial join.

Comment: We are not seeing your full code. You do not describe how you build the lists `statistics_fields_in` and `statistics_fields_out` and what should be in them, may be the issue is there?